# React router production build: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a very basic single page app I made using react-router. When I run the development express server locally, it works perfectly. However, when I run it on production, or locally run the production server, I can only access the homepage. If i type '/whatever' into my browser, I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
   at ServerResponse.sendFile (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:404:11)
   at c:\dev\BPL react\server.bundle.js:62:8
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at param (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)
   at param (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
   at Function.process_params (c:\dev\BPL react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
```

here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var compression = require('compression')

var app = express()

app.use(compression())

// serve our static stuff like index.css
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// send all requests to index.html so browserHistory works
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

I'm new to react and this has me totally stumped! Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have the file in the correct directory? What output do you get if you `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))` ?

Comment: Yes it's definitely correct. The output from that console.log() is '/public/index.html'.

Comment: But that's not the absolute path, and that's the error you are getting. If your server file is in the same level as the `public` dir try this:
`res.sendFile(path.resolve('public', 'index.html'))`, if it doesn't work tell me the output of that `path.resolve`.

Comment: You're right, that worked perfectly! Thanks so much!